# LL1 parsing algorithm for strings generated by a given grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

> How to describe a $\operatorname{LL(1)}$ parsing algorithm for strings generated by a given grammar?

I have to design a parser for a specific grammar.
Let $G$ be the grammar described as:

$$S \rightarrow aBC $$
$$B \rightarrow bB \mid cC $$
$$C \rightarrow c \mid S $$

#### My approach

**1. Test if the grammar is $\operatorname{LL(1)}$**

First I have to determine if the grammar is $\operatorname{LL(1)}$ or not. It seems that G is  $\operatorname{LL(1)}$ because:

$\operatorname{FIRST}(aBC) \cap \operatorname{FIRST}(bB \mid cC) \cap \operatorname{FIRST}(c \mid S) = 
\{a\} \cap \{b,c\} \cap \{c,a\} = \emptyset
$

**2. Write a string generated by G**

$s = abccaccc$

**3. Design the algorithm for parsing strings**

*I'm getting stuck here*

**4. Test the algorithm for a given string**

Lets test the algorithm for a given string $s = abccaccc$

Comment: What conflict do you see? Did you compute first and follow for the rules?

Comment: @HendrikJan First(B) = {b,c} ; First(C) = {c, a} . So First(B) $\cap$ First(C) = {c} then G is not LL(1). I don't have to compute follow because i don't see epsilon

Comment: @Jack: And in what context exactly might you have to choose between predicting a `B` and predicting a `C`?

Comment: Instead you must distinguish the first of "$bB$" vs. the first of "$cC$" to see whether the two productions for $B$ are used in different situations!

Comment: A language is a set of strings: it does not generate them, but a grammar does. Why jump on LL(1) parsing rather than some other technique: if it is a requirement of the problem, it should be stated in the question, not in the answer.

Comment: @HendrikJan now that i understood the grammar is  $\operatorname{LL1}$ how to do $\operatorname{LL1}$ parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibly useful quote from Aho, Lam et al ("the Dragon Book"). (Emphasis added.)

> A grammar $G$ is $LL(1)$ if and only if **whenever $a \to \alpha | \beta$ are two distinct productions of $G$**, the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. For no terminal $a$ do both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ derive strings beginning with $a$.
>
> …

Comment: thanks! But do you know how to design the algorithm?

Comment: See that book or some other textbook on compiler construction. Better still, use a parser generator (and you won't be restricted to LL(1) in most cases). Your question is to broad for this site, I think.